# indexing issues when extracting specified latitude and longitude

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples, typeerror

I want to extract a specified latitude and longitude from a `netCDF` file. In the past, I have never had issues with extracting the data. I am assuming that the reason it is not working this time is because I read in my data differently (see below)

```
data = netCDF4.Dataset('/home/eburrows/metr173/regional_cm/Lab1/air.mon.mean.nc', mode = 'r')
lat = data.variables['lat'][:] #90 through -90
lon = data.variables['lon'][:] #0 through 360
air_temp = data.variables['air'][:] #degrees C
air_temp[air_temp>10000] = n.NaN
```

Previously I have been able to do the following:

```
us_lat = n.ravel(n.where((lat>=___)&(lat<=___)))
us_lon = n.ravel(n.where((lon>=___)&(lon<=___)))
us_annual_temp = n.nanmean(air_temp[:,us_lat, us_lon],0)
```

This time however, it is returning a `Type Error` stating that `list indices must be integers, not tuple`.

I then forced the `tuple` into a `list` by changing `us_lat` and `us_lon` to have `list(n.ravel(n.where(...))`, but it still returns the same error. In the past I have been able to index this way and am not entirely sure why it is not working this time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of `lat_us` from the `where` command are a tuple of indices, not the actual indices that are needed for slicing `air_temp`.  To fix this, you need to index the first result from `lat_us` to access the array of latitude indices.

For instance,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lat = np.arange(-90,91,10)
>>> lat
array([-90, -80, -70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10,   0,  10,  20,  30,
    40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90])
>>> lat_us = np.where((lat >= -30) & (lat <= 30))
>>> lat_us
(array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12]),)
>>> lat_us[0]
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

So the line

```
us_lat = n.ravel(n.where((lat>=___)&(lat<=___)))
```

Should be modified to (note: I don't think you need to ravel this either):

```
us_lat = n.where((lat>=___) & (lat<=___))[0]
```

Also, you are currently reading in only one dimensional for the variable `air_temp`, but it appears to be 3D (time x lat x lon).  So you need to modify the read in of this variable to include all three dimensions:

```
air_temp = data.variables['air'][:,:,:]
```

Comment: Unfortunately with those modifications, it still returned the same error message. I also tried it without using ravel or the list function but neither option worked. The other attempts I tried appear as follows: us_lat = list(n.ravel(n.where((lat>=____)&(lat<=___))[0])) or us_lat = n.ravel(n.where((lat>=____)&(lat<=___))[0])

Comment: What are your results of `lat_us` and `lon_us`?  They should be an array of indices.  You can check this with `type(lat_us)` and it should return `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: After fixing a bug else where in the code, the type is returned <type 'numpy.ndarray' but it still returns a  type error when  try to form the us_annual_temp variable.